# how to prefix a var between spaces (in bash), then return concatenated strings to variable array?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, loops

for instance

```
var=${foo}

somecommand=${fofo -b -a -r}

for i in "${somecommand}" ; do
            echo   $i
        done
```

say this this returns a full line like

```
/bar /bar /bar
```

how would I prefix each instance returned into separate variable array?

```
newVar1=${foo}/bar
newVar2${foo}/bar
newVar3${foo}/bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a command `fofo -b -a -r` that outputs whitespace separated tokens like `/foo /bar /baz`, you can assign assign it to an array using:

```
myArray=( $(fofo -b -a -r) )
```

If you have a variable `foo=test`, you can prefix that to each element using

```
myPrefixedArray=( "${myArray[@]/#/$foo}" )
```

To wit:

```
foo=myprefix
myCmd() {
  echo /foo /bar /baz
}

myArray=( $(myCmd) )
myPrefixedArray=( "${myArray[@]/#/$foo}" )

echo "Values:"
for var in "${myPrefixedArray[@]}"
do
  echo "$var"
done
```

which prints

```
Values:
myprefix/foo
myprefix/bar
myprefix/baz
```